# #N/A when I try to use this IFS formula in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have been trying for hours to use these two formulas, where A2 is a random number:

```
=IFS(A2<=0.02,3368.7*A2,0.02<=A2<0.46,46.406*LN(A2)+245.66,0.46<A2<=0.59,-3252.4*(A2^2)-838.98,0.59<A2<=0.67,35.091*A2+274.45,0.67<A2<=0.83,1466.4*A2-689.81,0.83<A2,256.31*A2+315.02)

=IFS(U2<=0.01,97.675*U2+0.0071,0.01<U2<=0.42,41.88*U2+2.2726,0.42<U2,19.72)
```

It shows an #N/A error, I don't know what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0.02<=A2<0.46` is improper, one would use AND:

```
=AND(0.02<=A2,A2<0.46)
```

But it is not needed as IFS will resolve in order, It stops after if finds the first criterion that resolves to `TRUE`:

```
=IFS(A2<=0.02,3368.7*A2,A2<0.46,46.406*LN(A2)+245.66,A2<=0.59,-3252.4*(A2^2)-838.98,A2<=0.67,35.091*A2+274.45,A2<=0.83,1466.4*A2-689.81,TRUE,256.31*A2+315.02)
```

And

```
=IFS(U2<=0.01,97.675*U2+0.0071,U2<=0.42,41.88*U2+2.2726,TRUE,19.72)
```